# Parsing attribute in XML with DOM parser

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I am currently parsing XML, but im not quite sure how to parse the "status" attribute of "message":

```
<message status="test"> <text>sometext</text> <msisdn>stuff</msisdn> </message>
```

Here is the code, i have cut off everything unnecessary:

```
NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("message");

for (int s = 0; s < nodeLst.getLength(); s++) {

       Node fstNode = nodeLst.item(s);

       if (fstNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

               Element fstElmnt = (Element) fstNode;

               NodeList numberNmElmntLst = fstElmnt
               .getElementsByTagName("msisdn");
               Element numberNmElmnt = (Element) numberNmElmntLst.item(0);
               NodeList numberNm = numberNmElmnt.getChildNodes();
               String phoneNumber = ((Node) numberNm.item(0))
               .getNodeValue().substring(2);

               NodeList txtNmElmntLst = fstElmnt
               .getElementsByTagName("text");
               Element txtNmElmnt = (Element) txtNmElmntLst.item(0);
               NodeList txtNm = txtNmElmnt.getChildNodes();
               String text = ((Node) txtNm.item(0)).getNodeValue();

               NodeList rcvNmElmntLst = fstElmnt
               .getElementsByTagName("received");
               Element rcvNmElmnt = (Element) rcvNmElmntLst.item(0);
               NodeList rcvNm = rcvNmElmnt.getChildNodes();
               String recievedDate = ((Node) rcvNm.item(0)).getNodeValue();
            }
}
```

Can anyone guide me how this is done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Node.getAttributes()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getAttributes%28%29)

```
NamedNodeMap attributes = fstElmnt.getAttributes();

for (int a = 0; a < attributes.getLength(); a++) 
{
        Node theAttribute = attributes.item(a);
        System.out.println(theAttribute.getNodeName() + "=" + theAttribute.getNodeValue());
}
```

You could avoid traversing if you use XPATH to retrieve the data. Read [this tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you explain the attribute aNode?

Comment: @JavaCake aNode refers to the node for which you want to retrieve the attribute. In your case it is the Node referring to "message" element.

Comment: do you mind giving implementation example based on my code? I cant exactly determine how its done.

Comment: @JavaCake i edited my code. I assume "message" is the root element of your xml. if it is then it will work. try it and let me know. You can get the root element using doc.getDocumentElement() in DOM

Comment: @JavaCake i just realized "message" is not root element. you need to call that method on fstElmnt. i edited my code

Comment: It was easier than i thought. Thanks alot!

Comment: @JavaCake see my updated post, u could use xpath. also accept this as the answer if I answered ur question

Comment: `Node statusItem = attributes.getNamedItem("status");` did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I have been playing with [Apache Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/) for parsing DOM. But it was horrible tasks. If you could, take a look at [jsoup](http://jsoup.org).

So, if your question has an answer in Jsoup, it would be:

```
node.attr("status")
```

Comment: I regret i did not do that, but unfortunately i cannot change much now, the application is very big.