# Access svg path 'd' attribute

Tags: java, svg, batik

I have added SVG path element into a nodelist and I can print out the length of the list. May I know how to access the path 'd' attribute of the node.

svgDoc = domObj.createDoc(f.toURL().toString());
NodeList svgPathList = svgDoc.getElementsByTagName("path");

I have already tried this but it doesn't work.

svgPathList.item(0).getNodeValue();

Comment: Not sure in java, but with the dom you can often do something like item[0].getAttribute("d")

Comment: I have already found the answer from here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132778/parsing-attribute-in-xml-with-dom-parser
Thanks